# Android ImageView Background image and color Collide

Tags: android

is there a way around this? i can only have one of them, either bg color or drawable.

```
 @Override
public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds.get((mThumbIds.size()-1)-position));

    //the part where only one works
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fab_icon_bg);
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    setAnimation(imageView,position);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(180, 180));

    return imageView;
}
```

i can't use drawable because it's in an adapter and "getResources()" is not recognized.

Comment: you can create drawable for out desired effect.

Comment: What do you mean?can you explain or show me a snippet?

Comment: what is your real prob??where u get error?

Comment: cannot understand what problem you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your *"getResources()" is not recognized*

In your adapter constructor pass context  like this..

```
public class MyAdaptet extend BaseAdapter{

private Context ctx;

public MyAdapter(Context context){
     this.ctx=context;
}
```

And use this **ctx** to get your drawables like

`ctx.getResource()` etc...

}